# SQL Server query performance suddenly degrades after data insertion

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Context: we have a SQL Server 2019 database containing outputs of a scenario modelling process (this was also happening on a SQL Server 2017 Express implementation).

Each instance of the model creates a complete set of data in a set of standard tables. The instance identifier is a key column in each table.

This data is then transformed into a star schema for visualisation and analysis.
The queries that join tables to create the star schema typically run in a few 10s of seconds to return 500,000 - 5,000,000 rows to populate the fact table of the star schema.

**Problem**: when a new instance is added often one or more of the queries takes hundreds of times longer. When run interactively in SSMS I am seeing around 10,000 rows a minute being returned. To get to 1 million this takes over an hour, where previously it was taking 20 seconds to return 880,000 rows.

This occurs both when running the simple query in SSMS with one 'instance ID' in the where clause, or whether this is done through a stored procedure that runs several queries to populate a fact table.

A rebuild of the indexes restores the previous performance.

Given that rebuilding the indexes becomes increasingly expensive as we have more instances in the database, are there other approaches to fixing this sort of performance blow-out?

Comment: have you tried updating statistics : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have you checked the `Actual Execution Plan` to see if you're experiencing loss of performance due to [parameter sniffing](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/)?

Comment: I'm with Hogan. Sounds like stale statistics which leads Query Planner to make bad decisions on the current data shape.

Comment: How much disk space is occupied by one 'instance'?  How much RAM is used by SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Hogan and Dakota Methvin.  Today I had a case where it simply didn't appear to be doing anything (checking Live Query Statistics of the Actual Execution Plan).  I did `Update Statistics` progressively on each of the source tables and the query eventually came through with 790K rows in 14 seconds.  Very happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be that the tempDB is hitting an upper threshold (disk space).  Re-building indexes will clean up some space for a bit but it can start cranking back up again and cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue was provided by @Hogan.  After a bulk insertion for a new instance into the database do `update statistics` on each of the tables added to.
The existing statistics have no knowledge of the new instance ID and so SQL builds a plan that assumes 1 resulting record, instead of the million or so actually present.
This has made a difference of around 100-500 times in execution time and cost.